# How should I share functions between files in C?

Tags: c

Say I have 3 files: `code.h`, `code.c`, and `foo.c`, and that they look something like this:

code.h:

```
#ifndef CODE_H_INCLUDED
#define CODE_H_INCLUDED

void C_SomeFunction(void);

#endif
```

code.c:

```
#include "code.h"

extern void C_DoStuff(void);

void C_SomeFunction(void)
{
        // ...

        C_DoStuff();

        // ...
}
```

foo.c:

```
#include "code.h"

void C_DoStuff(void)
{
        // ...
}
```

If I don't want to allow includers of `code.h` to call `C_DoStuff()` directly, but I would still like to use it in `code.c`, would this be the right way to do so? The reason I haven't defined `C_DoStuff()` in `code.c` as static is because in a real project, I have many of these functions, and defining them all in one file would make the file too large for my liking.

Comment: You will have to allow includes of `code.h` -- that is where you provide the *function prototype* for use by the other code. It doesn't matter whether you provide your code in a library or compile it when `foo.c` is compiled. The linker will need to know what function to look for (so it can include the code for it) and that is satisfied when you provide the function prototype. Otherwise, just write another `static` function of `C_DoStuff()` in the other source.

Comment: Applied to a function, the `extern` keyword does nothing -- that is the default.

Comment: Yes, this is the right way to do so. Unrelated of that, it doesn't seem like you need to include `code.h` in `foo.c`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: without `extern void C_DoStuff(void)`, the file `code.c` would not compile.

Comment: The way you have your code split with `void C_DoStuff(void)` in `foo.c` you need to add the prototype to `code.h` or link `foo.c` when you compile `code.c`. Trying to find ways around doing it the right way is never a good idea...

Comment: @Elliott: That does not contradict what I wrote though.

Comment: @Elliott: Well, your assumption was probably based on the fact that my comment was in response to a comment on `extern` alone. So it's probably "half my bad" as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you do not want to "publish" the function `C_DoStuff()`. The standard way to avoid that is to declare it `static`. However, this means that the same instance of the function cannot be shared between modules.

I do not think there is one solution that fits all situations, but if `C_DoStuff()` is small or only used by `code.c`, a possibility is to include `foo.c` from `code.c`.

Thus `code.c` would look like this:

```
#include "code.h"

#include "foo.c"  // Implementation of C_DoStuff()

void C_SomeFunction(void)
{
        // ...

        C_DoStuff();

        // ...
}
```

And `foo.c` would look like this (you may want to give the file another extension, though, e.g. `foo.c.inc`):

```
#include "code.h"  // Only if needed for the contents of C_DoStuff()

static void C_DoStuff(void)
{
        // ...
}
```

The drawback is that if `C_DoStuff()` is also needed in another module, then that module would also need to include `foo.c` and thus a second copy of the function would be created. As with most solutions, this pattern has its uses and misuses.